# Long running stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, database-administration

A SQL Server 2000 stored procedure has been running for more than 4 hrs.

The stored procedure consists of an `insert` statement, also several intermediate temp tables insertions. When checked the first temp table data, it shows the table does not exist.It seems it has not yet created the

Is there any way to find out what has happened in SQL Server 2000 or in which step the stored procedure is running?

Comment: Unless you are using the same connection, the temp table will not be visible to you.

Comment: Most likely scenario if it does not normally do that is that the sp is being blocked by some other process. Did you check for blocks?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific, are you trying to remove this stored procedure? Which step of what? A long SQL statement, a computer program. Did you create the query? Could you post an example. Right now all I can tell you is to reverse the polarity of the INSERT statement(Works in Star Trek, right).